# HTML5 file slice + upload = recursive closure?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload, html5-filesystem

I'm splitting an extremely large file (10's of GBs) into chunks to upload via HTML5's File API.

My code basically looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
function sendChunk() {
   var formData = new FormData();
   var blob = file.slice(offset, finish);
   formData.append('data', blob);
   $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function() {
         if (! done) {
            advanceCounters();
            sendChunk();
         }
      }
      ...
   });    
}
```

The issue been, I'm creating an ever deeper and deeper closure. I can't really see any other way around this? Am I missing something? Just let the closure build until it finally unwinds? Use timers to look for a "do more now" state?

Comment: There is only one closure there and no recursion since inner setchunk will be called long after the outer has finished.

Comment: @Musa there is no recursion, but are you sure the nested closures does not exists here

Comment: Initially I was but no so much any more.

Comment: As the call stack gets deeper, the nested closures will get deeper too.

Comment: The call stack is not getting deeper.  `$.ajax` is an async call.  `sendChunk()` returns immediately after `$.ajax` is executed, before the `success` function is invoked.

Comment: give your success function a name and make it a sibling of sendChunk if in doubt. it usually helps development to un-nest async callbacks in general, IOC ...